# Zoom Email in Response to an Unusual Log In

Tags: zoom.us

I have a question. I received the below message when trying to log into my Zoom account:

We detected an unusual login from a device or location you don't usually use or have not used in a while. To sign in to your Zoom account, check your email and input the verification code below.

Can you tell me what the email sent to my inbox looks like? Does it provide the location from where the device attempted to log into zoom? Or, does the email only provide the verification code? In short, I want to know if the location where the log-in happened is provided in the email.

Answer (score -1):

This is the information they send on the email:

Date    XX/XX/2022 07:57:34 PM
Browser Chrome
Operating System    XX
Location    Lyon(FR)

I hope this helps